# Mobile Signature problem. Document has been altered or corrupted since it was created

Tags: c#, digital-signature, itext7

i am developing a mobile signature application with .net and Itext. The problem is when i add the sign to the pdf file it says document is altered. When i parse the responce XML i can get the user certificate and base64 sign value. Then i added it to the pdf with itext it says document was altered or corrupted.

```
public Envelope Imzala() {

        Byte[] bytes = null;
        PdfReader pdfReader = null;
        FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(@"C:\mobilimza\imzasiz.pdf");
        byte[] hashValue = null;
        using (SHA256 mySHA256 = SHA256.Create())
        {
            using (FileStream fileStream = fInfo.Open(FileMode.Open))
            {
                pdfReader = new PdfReader(fileStream);
                try
                {
                    fileStream.Position = 0;
                    hashValue = mySHA256.ComputeHash(fileStream);


                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"I/O Exception: {e.Message}");
                }
            }
        }
        bytes = hashValue;
        DataToBeSigned = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);

        string soapResult = string.Empty;
        XmlDocument responseXML = new XmlDocument();
        try
        {
            WebRequest webRequest = CreateWebRequest(GlobalParameters.imzaServisLink);
            XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = new XmlDocument();



            string xml1 = @""// my sign request;


            soapEnvelopeXml.LoadXml(xml1);
            using (Stream stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                soapEnvelopeXml.Save(stream);
            }
            using (WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse())
            {


                using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
                    Envelope envelope;
                    var mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Envelope));
                    using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(soapResult))
                    {
                        envelope = (Envelope)mySerializer.Deserialize(reader);

                        string base64sign = envelope.Body.MSS_SignatureResponse.MSS_SignatureResp.MSS_Signature.Base64Signature;

                        byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(base64sign);

                        string decodedText = "<Root>" + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data) + "</Root>";

                        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                        xmlDoc.LoadXml(decodedText);


                        XmlElement keyInfoElement = (XmlElement)xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//KeyInfo");
                        XmlElement x509CertificateElement = (XmlElement)keyInfoElement.SelectSingleNode(".//X509Certificate");

                        XmlElement signvalue = (XmlElement)xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(".//SignatureValue");

                        if (x509CertificateElement != null)
                        {
                            string x509CertificateText = x509CertificateElement.InnerText;
                            string signText = signvalue.InnerText;
                            byte[] x509data = Convert.FromBase64String(x509CertificateText);
                            X509Certificate2 x509 = new(x509data);

                            PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(@"c:\mobilimza\imzali.pdf");

                            StampingProperties sp = new StampingProperties();
                            sp.UseAppendMode();
                            PdfSigner pdfSigner = new PdfSigner(pdfReader, pdfWriter, sp);

                            PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = pdfSigner.GetSignatureAppearance();

                            //pdfSigner.SetFieldName("Signature");
                            //appearance.SetPageNumber(1);

                            // Set the X.509 certificate chain
                            X509CertificateParser parser = new X509CertificateParser();
                            Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[] chain = new Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[] { DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(x509) };

                            pdfSigner.SignDetached(new CustomExternalSignature1(Convert.FromBase64String(signText)), chain, null, null, null, 0, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS);

                        }

                        return envelope;
                    }


                }


            }
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gi9z8.jpg)

Comment: You add a signature for the original pdf. That is the wrong approach. Pdf signatures require the document first to be prepared for signing (in particular adding a placeholder for the new signature and some wrapping thereof), then hashing that prepared pdf (except the placeholder gap), creating a signature value for that hash, and embedding that signature value.

Comment: I already try to preapare the document for signing but i cant achive the solution. How d o i add necessary gap to original pdf?

Comment: I just wanted to write an answer but looking at the details of your code I realized that there is a problem:  You retrieve the certificate (`x509CertificateElement`) and the signature (`signvalue`) in the same response. For many signature container profiles, though, you need the certificate already when building the data-to-be-signed. Thus, does your signing service allow to retrieve the certificate in a separate call before the actual signature creation call?

Comment: yes mssp service have a profilequery service. the response has CertIssuerDN, CertSerialNumber, DigestMethod, DigestValue and certIssuerDN-DER. But i cant figure out how to construct an X509certificate object from this values.

Comment: *"mssp service have a profilequery service. the response has CertIssuerDN, CertSerialNumber, DigestMethod, DigestValue and certIssuerDN-DER. But i cant figure out how to construct an X509certificate object from this values"* - Indeed, that's not the whole certificate, just some information to identify it. It is possible to create valid signatures with it, even PAdES if need be. But existing routines to create signatures usually expect the whole certificate up front. So you will likely have to do some custom coding here.